# not able to use custom classes in @apply in scss file tailwind nextjs project?

Tags: css, sass, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use a custom class `overflow:inherit` as `@apply overflow-inherit` in `tailwind` `next.js` project but it's throwing error. However, I can `@apply` pre-built tailwind classes like `@apply flex flex-col md:h-full h-screen;` but not custom.

Full repo: https://github1s.com/GorvGoyl/Personal-Site-Gourav.io

tailwind.scss:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  @variants responsive {
    .overflow-inherit {
      overflow: inherit;
    }
  }
}
```

project.module.scss:

```
.css {
  :global {
    .wrapper-outer {
      @apply overflow-inherit; //trying to apply custom utility
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
wait  - compiling...
event - build page: /next/dist/pages/_error
error - ./layouts/css/project.module.scss:4:6
Syntax error: C:\Users\1gour\Personal-Site\project.module.scss The `overflow-inherit` class does not exist, but `overflow-hidden` does. If you're sure that `overflow-inherit` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.

  2 |   :global {
  3 |     .wrapper-outer {
> 4 |       @apply overflow-inherit;
    |      ^
  5 |     }
  6 |   }
```

postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

- "next": "^10.0.7",
- "tailwindcss": "^2.0.3",
- "sass": "^1.32.8",
- "postcss": "^8.2.6",

Comment: I don't have any experience with Tailwind, but, maybe, you are calling `@apply overflow-inherit` before it gets defined, as SASS uses top-to-bottom flow of control. Even when importing modules, they should be imported in order.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/andybroger/nextjs-tailwindcss/tree/jsx-tailwind

Comment: @Leo I followed what tailwind suggested in their docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities

Comment: @GorvGoyl did you found solution already? Edit: In git I see that you took tailwind plugin approach, something that I want to avoid :(

Comment: yeah i didn't like that too but it seems like the only approach so far... see https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/3754#

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Laravel project.

I decided that `postcss` is not enough for me. So in the `webpack.mix.js` I deleted the following

```
mix.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
]);
```

and replaced it with `sass` like this

```
mix.sass("resources/css/app.scss", "public/css").options({
    postCss: [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ], });
```

Now, I got a number of cool features including the one you want

I don't even need to use `@layer`

in my scss file I can combine `@apply` and `@extend` and it works

```
.btn-my-theme{
    @apply rounded border py-2 px-3 shadow-md hover:shadow-lg;
}

.btn-my-primary{
    @extend .btn-my-theme;
    @apply text-blue-600 bg-blue-200 hover:bg-blue-100 border-blue-500;
}

.btn-my-secondary{
    @extend .btn-my-theme;
    @apply text-gray-600 bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100 border-gray-500;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Set CSS validate in "Workspace/.vscode/settings.json"

```
"css.validate": false,
```

or "User/settings.json"

```
"css.validate": false,
```

like this [link](https://github.com/zhixiangyao/vite-react-ts-starter/blob/main/.vscode/settings.json#L3)

Comment: could you please add some context about your code snippet i.e. where to add it