# tailwind: how to use @apply for custom class in nuxt2?

Tags: css, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to use `@apply` on my custom class in Nuxt.js 2

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
export default {
    buildModules: [
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    ],
    tailwindcss: {
        cssPath: '~/assets/app.css',
        exposeConfig: true
    }
}
```

**assets/app.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
    .btn {
        @apply border-2 p-2 font-bold;
    }
}
```

in any vue-single-file or any other scss file

```js
<style lang="scss">
    .btn-lg {
        @apply btn;
    }
</style>
```

[image: The btn class does not exist. If you're sure that btn exists, make sure that any @import statements are being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as @apply can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree]

> The `btn` class does not exist. If you're sure that `btn` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree

**So, how to make my custom styles be seen by the Tailwind CSS before processing to make my custom classes work in `@apply`?**

---

I've tried the solutions in the following questions and document

- [adding-custom-utilities](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-custom-utilities)
- [not able to use custom classes in @apply in scss file tailwind nextjs project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66639623/not-able-to-use-custom-classes-in-apply-in-scss-file-tailwind-nextjs-project)

But none of them work

---

I am using:

- Tailwindcss **2.2.19** via @nuxtjs/tailwindcss
- Nuxt.js 2.15.8

Thanks a lot for any replies!

Comment: Fine, it seems to be a bug in nuxtjs/tailwindcss: [Custom utility: @apply can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.](https://github.com/nuxt-community/tailwindcss-module/issues/140), just add a `mode:"jit"` can solve this problem

Comment: Post this as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, add a `mode: "jit"` can solve this problem.

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit'
}
```

It's a good vanilla solution.

---

However, if you are programming the project in a virtual machine(Homestead) just like me, this could cause a error that the node can't recoginze the changings of your css/scss/sass files.

so there's another two solutions:

1. use pure `tailwindcss` instead of `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss`

   just follow the document: [Install Tailwind CSS with Nuxt.js](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs)
2. use `plugin()` in your `tailwind.config.css`

   > ```js
   > const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
   > const fs = require('fs')
   > module.exports = {
   >   // ... purge, theme, variants, ...
   >   plugins: [
   >     plugin(function({ addUtilities, postcss }) {
   >       const css = fs.readFileSync('./your-custom-style-file-path', 'utf-8')
   >       addUtilities(postcss.parse(css).nodes)
   >     }),
   >  ],
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > [from github](https://github.com/nuxt-community/tailwindcss-module/issues/140#issuecomment-911997165)

But what's more, this solution can't recoginze the changings too. So add your css/scss/sass files in `nuxt.config.js` (I'm using `nuxt-vite`)

```js
vite: {
    plugins: [
        {
            name: 'watch-external', // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373804/rollup-watch-include-directory/63548394#63548394
            async buildStart(){
                const files = await fg(['assets/**/*']);
                for(let file of files){
                    this.addWatchFile(file);
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: With tailwindcss 3, it comes with a standalone CLI - https://tailwindcss.com/blog/standalone-cli - can this be used instead of including tailwindcss in node ?